# Selecionar texto do textarea ao clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer para, quando clicar em um determinado `button`, o texto de um determinado `textarea` ou `input` ser selecionado?

Queria respostas com soluções com jQuery e também sem jQuery (javascript puro).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em jQuery você simplesmente utiliza o evento [select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/);

```js
$('#btnSelecionar').click(function(){
$('#txtInput').select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtInput">
Testando textarea stackoverflow. 
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Selecionar" id="btnSelecionar"/>
```

Em javascript você vai seguir a mesma lógica. Seleciona o elemento e utiliza o método [select()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_select.asp) para selecionar o texto. Ficando assim:

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtInput">
Testando textarea stackoverflow. 
</textarea>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Selecionar</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("txtInput").select();
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 Sem brincadeira, @Randrade, não pensei que fosse tão fácil!

Comment: Agora, tem como mostrar um exemplo em somente javascript?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Está ai

Comment: Valeu, amigo!!!

Comment: No IE do Windows Phone apertar esse "selecionar" fecha o navegador, hahahaha #partiu reportar bug.

Comment: @renan Quero pelo menos 1% do que ganhar! kkk

Answer (score 5):

**Jquery:**

```
 $(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=example1]', function() {
     this.select();
   });
 });
```

**JS Puro:**

```
document.getElementById("example2").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("example2").select();
}
```

```js
 $(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=example1]', function() {
     this.select();
   });
 });

document.getElementById("example2").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("example2").select();
}
```

```html
JQuery:

<input type="text" id="example1" value="click the input to select" onclick="this.select();"/>


Js Puro:
<input type="text" id="example2" value="click the input to select" onclick="this.select();"/>
```