# Selecionar Texto do 'Textarea' com Variáveis ao Clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery

No caso abaixo:

[Selecionar texto do textarea ao clicar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92727/selecionar-texto-do-textarea-ao-clicar/364003)

Se eu quiser uma variável example1, example2, exampleN. Como eu declaro no *jQuery*? Eu não posso fazer assim...

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=valor_unitario"+id+"]', function() {
     this.select();
```

Correto?

E como faço para inserir no *jQuery* mais de uma input(por exemplo: exampleN e helpN)? também não posso assim...

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=valor_unitario1]', , 'input[type=text][id=quantidade1]', function() {
     this.select();
```

Certo? Neste caso seria correto assim...

```js
$(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=valor_unitario1]', function() {
     this.select();
   });
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=qnt1]', function() {
     this.select();
   });
 });
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da maneira que você colocou, passando como parâmetro os elementos desejados, só que você deve coloca-los em um mesmo parâmetro separado por vírgula, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=text][id=valor_unitario1], input[type=text][id=quantidade1]', function() {
     this.select();
}
```

Porém não é uma boa maneira de fazer isso. A melhor maneira é você colocar uma classe em cada elemento, e no evento 'click' você atribuir ela uma única vez, por exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.copiaTexto', function() {
   this.select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="copiaTexto" rows="5" cols="51">
Texto para ser copiado
</textarea>

<textarea class="copiaTexto" rows="5" cols="51">
Texto para ser copiado 2
</textarea>
```

Desta forma, toda classe que possuir "copiaTexto" irá receber este evento, inclusive as que você adicionar dinamicamente, se for o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar `[id^=valor_unitario]` para selecionar todos os elementos em que o id começa com "valor_unitário".

Você também pode separar sua query com uma virgula para selecionar todos os elementos desejados

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=valor_unitario], [id^=qnt]', function() {
  this.select();
});
```

Mas seria muito mais performático e mais fácil de manter se você simplesmente atribuísse uma classe em comum a esses elementos, e então fizesse a query por classe, ao invés de utilizar uma substring do id.